Why is BigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal, MathContext) slower than BigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal)?
I'm trying to perform a recursive operation using arbitrary decimal scale.
However, as the recursion is repeated, the required precision also doubles, so it must be cut off at a certain level.
I found the appropriate method is BigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal, MathContext), but it is strangely slow than BigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal).
After checking the internal code, I found that BigDecimal.divideAndRound() is the main cause of poor performance. Does it take this slow?
Below is a simple code to see the performance.
 public static void main(String[] args) {
               BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.4320843204893290423");
        b = b.pow(20);
        int times = 1000000;

        MathContext context = new MathContext(100, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        BigDecimal[] arr = new BigDecimal[times];
        BigDecimal a;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) { //59ms
            a = b.multiply(b);
            arr[i] = a;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).sum());

        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) { //2542ms
            a = b.multiply(b, context);
            arr[i] = a;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).sum());
    }
}


scsale() or setScale() ? Also check How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?

( for example: BigDecimal is immutable, all posted operations [multiply(), setScale()] return a new instance which is being discarded, so the JIT compiler can just skip the whole operation and even the whole loop )

"but this method controls precision, not scale, so it is inappropriate if the value is 0 or very small" - that doesn't make sense. The whole point of this was to prevent precision growing out of control. Setting all your numbers to a fixed scale doesn't do that.

a different question after the edit... I would never expect that the two-argument method is faster than the 1-argument one, since the first calculation has an additional constraint

Since my previous question was too vague, I reposted it to summarize what I really needed to know.....

The way the code is written any half decent optimising compiler will skip the benchmark loops entirely for i>0 since none of those results are actually used. Benchmarking code must be very careful not to leave loopholes where a smart optimiser can avoid doing most of the work. IOW you need to println( a[times-1] ) to make sure it does all of the work inside the loop.

Thanks for the suggestion. I added the sum code and tested again, but the time it took was similar to above.

you call that "summarize"?! From "Why is scale() (setScale()) slow" to "Why is multiply(BigDecimal, MathContext) slower than multiply(BigDecimal)" - not only the title, also the content ... for me it is a different question (OK, still about BigDecimal) BTW tested (code of actual question) with JMH and can confirm the 2-parameter method is about 10 times slower than the 1-paramter one (but I am no JMH expert, just curious)

Oops, there was a wording mistake. I apologize for this,,,,

Yes, rounding to the given number of decimal places involves exponentiation and division, which is an order of magnitude slower than multiplication.
